# Is it possible to formulate general relativity via quaternions?

Tags: reference-request, quaternions, general-relativity

### Background

I was fiddling around and wondered about the below.

Consider the following quaternions:

$$i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1$$

Consider the analog of the line element:

$$ ds = dx i + dy j + dz k + \alpha dt$$

where  $\alpha$ is a gauge function. Squaring both sides:

$$ ds^2 = - dx^2  - dy^2 - dz^2 + \alpha^2 dt^2 + 2 \alpha dx dt i + 2 \alpha dy dt j+ 2 \alpha dz dt k$$

We choose $\alpha$ such that:

$$ \alpha^2 + 2\alpha \frac{dx}{dt} i+ 2\alpha \frac{dy}{dt} j+ 2\alpha \frac{dz}{dt}k = c^2$$

Hence,

$$ ds^2 = c^2 dt^2 - dx^2 - dy^2 - dz^2 $$

### Question

Is it possible to formulate general relativity this way? Have people already combined general relativity and quaternions?

Comment: Have a look at this. Before thinking about General Relativity I think you should consider the "simpler" question "are quaternions useful in Special Relativity"? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169758/226902

Comment: Related to the reformulation of special relativity in terms of quaternions: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9508011

Comment: @Quillo thanks for the links. I asked about General Relativity since I was hoping that the singularity would be less of a problem there (in the quaternion formulation) ?